# Web Browser Control, setting timeout value

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm using a web browser in C# to execute a PHP file on the localhost server. This PHP script actually gets information from another website and parses it.

On my personal laptop, that has Windows 8 and Internet Explorer Version 10, this PHP script executes just fine in Internet Explorer, Firefox and also within my C# application's web browser.

On my friends computer, that has a Windows 7 and Internet Explorer Version 10, the same PHP script executes just fine in Firefox. However, both in Internet Explorer and my C# applications Web Browser, I get "This page can't be displayed".

Stripping down the PHP script in question (connect to the web page and echo "hello" without waiting for a response from the remote server and without parsing that response) it works just fine.

This leads me to believe that there must be a timeout with a shorter waiting time in my friends Internet Explorer/C# Web Browser component. It's the only explanation I can come up with.

Can I manually set the Web Browser Timeout to a different value in C#?

If someone suspects that this is not the problem, I would truly value your input.

Comment: Could you define which C# web browser you are using? I'm guessing you're using some kind of library?

Comment: I'm actually just using the Web Browser control in the toolbar. The one that's included in Visual Studio by default (sorry I don't have much experience in C#).

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms program, or a WPF program?

Comment: Windows Forms program

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser doesn't have any timeout beyond the normal TCP/IP stack connection and receive timeouts.  Which are hard-wired in Windows, there's no api to change them.  You can add registry keys to override the timeouts but that only allows making them longer.  Otherwise a consequence of the way TCP/IP works, you can never predict how long a connection attempt is going to take because there's no simple way to discover how far the machine is located and how many router hops or *which* routers will be used to get there.

You'll need to look for another reason.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean but this leaves me in a total mystery then. Exact same page opens up in Firefox of both computers. Exact same page opens up in Internet Explorer on one computer, and "this page can't be displayed" on the other computer. At this point I'm not even worried about my C# application as I'm pretty sure C# Web Browser is just based on the internet explorer on that system.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. WinINET maintains its own timeouts. See this well-written KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050. To change the default values for your own application, call InternetSetOption with the desired timeout type and new value.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure we'd all appreciate a code snippet from a former IE team member that shows how to get the HINTERNET out of WebBrowser.

Comment: Sorry, Hans, I think I misread your answer: When you said "TCP/IP stack connection and receive timeouts" I now think you're referring to the timeouts that WinINET is assigning; these aren't from TCP/IP itself. I don't think it's correct to say that the values only "allow making them longer." And yes, getting the HINTERNET is non-trivial; I'd assumed that this was one of the settings whereby you could pass HINTERNET of null, but alas I no longer have source access to look at this.